# Sonarqube with Nginx sub-location not loading js/css files

Tags: nginx, sonarqube, reverse-proxy

When I am trying to access **SERVER_IP:9000** from browser, sonarqube is loading perfectly fine.

Whereas for **SERVER_IP/sonarqube**, I am getting this error:

> > Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) vendors-main.m.428bef42.chunk.js:1

[image: Error image]

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    sendfile            on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            #root       html;
            #index      index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/;
        }

        location = /sonarqube {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:9000/;
        }

        error_page      500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root        html;
        }

        location ~ \.css {
            add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        }
        location ~ \.js {
            add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the context which you have configured on Nginx on sonar.properties file.

Go to, sonar.properties file and give sonar.web.context value as per your nginx context configuration

sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
sonar.web.port=9000

Now restart sonarqube. it will work!